# Deep Learning for Ordinal Classification

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Can we use any of the various types of Deep Neural Networks for Ordinal Classification? If yes, then how? If no, then what is the limiting problem?
I know that CovNets with a softmax output can be used for classification between n classes. Is there a way this can be extended/modified for ordinal classification?

Finally, I would like both class label and its ordinal output.

I think ordinal classification is part of regression (please clarify). So, I am asking for a DNN that can do both classification and regression. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches. One is to do a one in hot encoding:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1028.pdf

But there should be other approaches. In classical ordinal regression, we fit cut off values st:

- $ P(X=1) = P(Z \leq \theta_1) = F(\theta_1)$
- $ P(X=2) = P(\theta_1 \leq Z \leq \theta_2) = F(\theta_2) - F(\theta_1)$
- $ P(X=3) = P(Z \geq \theta_2) = 1- F(\theta_2)$

Where Z is some latent variable and F is the CDF of the latent variable. It should be possible to directly apply this approach where Z is the second to last layer (the layer before the softmax).

Comment: Note that you are (properly) answering with regard to probability estimation.  The original question was falsely put in terms of 'classification'.

Comment: Once you have a probability for each class, the typical approach is then to choose the most probable class.

Comment: Please don't do that unless there is a class that has a probability above 0.95 for all observations.  If probabilities are more spread out there is too much uncertainty to ignore close calls.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Where do you get 0.95 as opposed to, say, 0.90 or 0.99?

Comment: You could say 0.99 but not so much 0.9.  A probability of 0.9 means you'll be wrong 0.1 of the time if you classify it as "positive" and 0.1 may be too large.